# Firebase stored file json information

Tags: android, json, firebase, firebase-storage

I have uploaded some images/videos on Firebase. Does firebase provide json information about uploaded content in paginated format. In the friendly-pix sample uploaded images were mapped in the database and then manually fetched with the url obtained from db.

I'm looking for a direct way as my app doesn't have concept of users right now. I basically need to get json information about uploaded content and then show them in the app directly.

Comment: If you are looking whether you can get a file/object listing from Firebase Storage, the answer is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37335102/how-to-get-an-array-with-all-pictures/37337436#37337436