# How can i download a file which contain images?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage

I want to provide a feature that user can review all images which are uploaded by them. In my firebase storage, it contains user's images in `/$uid/image` folder.

```
/$uid/image/imageA.png
/$uid/image/imageB.png
/$uid/image/imageC.png
```

However, i don't know how to get the reference of full users file.
i tried the code below to download it, but I got a `storage/object-not-found` error code.

```
var imageRef = storageRef.child('UserImage/'+ user.uid + '/image');
```

i just want to get a list of image's download url in Json format. 
For example,

```
{$uid/image:[
  'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX1',
  'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX2',
  'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX3'
]}
```

Comment: There is currently no API to get all files in a folder from Firebase Storage. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37335102/how-to-get-an-array-with-all-pictures/37337436#37337436

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you are not missing a "/" here:

```
var imageRef = storageRef.child('UserImage/'+ user.uid + 'image');
                                                    here ^
```

Also make sure you include the actual file at the end of the reference (`/image.png`), not the users subtree of images.

Use this function:

```
imageRef.getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {
    // Get the download URL for '<reference>'
    // store the url, do something with it
}).catch(function(error) {
    // Handle any errors
});
```

You could then add these to an array or whatever you please.

Reference: [getDownloadURL()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files#download_data_via_url)

Comment: i have already use this, so i can catch the error then log the error code in console..

Comment: Then grab the url thats passed into the success, and check to make sure your path is correct. I have edited my answer

Comment: i got an error which is `storage/object-not-found`. Also, my path should be correct because it get all right if i try to use `UserImage/'+ user.uid + '/image/' + 'imageA.png'`.

Comment: @ theblindprophet actual file? Does it mean that i cannot download a folder from firebase?