# Download multiple image's data at a path containing >1 image - Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-storage

If I have a path in Google Firebase Storage that looks like this... `userUID/creationDate` and I have more than 1 image stored at that path, how can I download all images at that location?

For example, can I just tell firebase to download all data at `userUID/creationDate`?

Or, for each image, do I need to download directly from the url (e.g. `userUID/creationDate/image1.jpg` & `userUID/creationDate/image2.jpg`)?

I'm using Swift in an iOS project.

Thanks! All feedback is much appreciated.

Comment: There is currently no API to list or download all images in a folder. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37335102/how-to-get-an-array-with-all-pictures

Comment: Excellent thank you!