# GET gs://example.appspot.com/images net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, firebase, firebase-storage

I've been getting this error message lately and I wonder why.

> GET gs://example.appspot.com/images net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME

Below are my references to the storage service:

```
var storage = firebase.storage();

var storageRef = storage.ref();

var storageRefImgs = storageRef.child('images');
```

I have Google Chrome 51 and I'm running Windows 10.

Comment: what kind of error are you getting?

Comment: your browser doesn't understand `gs://` which is normally `http://` or `https://`. Perhaps you need an extension?

Comment: @ShanmugapriyaD here is the error I was getting: "GET gs://example.appspot.com/images net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME"

Comment: @Icycool the issue was with the gs:// URL

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems like you're putting the `gs://` URL (which is an internal Google Storage reference) into a control that can't handle it (such as an `img` tag).

If you want to use the file in an `img` tag, you'll have to [get the download URL](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files#download_data_via_url) for the file. From the documentation:

```
storageRef.child('images/stars.jpg').getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {
  // Get the download URL for 'images/stars.jpg'
  // This can be inserted into an <img> tag
  // This can also be downloaded directly
}).catch(function(error) {
  // Handle any errors
});
```

Comment: this seems to work. Thanks a lot. Now, I,m not using an <img> tag, instead, I'm using a "background-image: url('img/pic.png')" in a <div>. I'll post another question for that, since this question answered.

Comment: what should I need to do to get all files from a location?

Comment: That's unrelated to this question, but see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37335102/how-to-get-an-array-with-all-pictures/37337436#37337436