# Determining the number of elements in Firebase storage using Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I am trying to figure the function which returns the number of items in Firebase storage and also getting access to those items. The names of the items are randomly generated so I can't access them directly.

Comment: There is currently no API to access the items in (a folder in) Firebase Storage as a collection. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37335102/how-to-get-an-array-with-all-pictures

Comment: How do we use the snapshot method for Firebase database?

Comment: @DannyTan I'd check out the docs on this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/retrieve-data