# getDownloadURL and post to Firebase Database on Android sometimes doesn't work

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I am trying to upload an image to Firebase when creating a new user and get the image `downloadUrl` and post it to my realtime database as part of the users details. Sometimes the `downloadUrl` gets posted, sometimes it doesn't get posted but the image always uploads successfully. This is my code, am I doing something wrong? Please help...

upload image method

```
private void postImage() {
        String path = "userProfiles/" + UUID.randomUUID() + ".jpeg";
        StorageReference userProfilesRef = storage.getReference(path);
        userProfilesRef.putFile(filePath).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                 downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl().toString();


                //if the upload is successfull
                //hiding the progress dialog

            }
        });
    }
```

registering user method

```
private void registerUser(){
        postImage();
        //getting email and password from edit texts
        String email = editTextEmail.getText().toString().trim();
        final String username = editTextUsername.getText().toString().trim();
        final String password  = editTextPassword.getText().toString().trim();



        //checking if email and passwords are empty
        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(email)){
            Toast.makeText(this,"Please enter email",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }

        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(password)){
            Toast.makeText(this,"Please enter password",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }



        //if the email and password are not empty
        //displaying a progress dialog

        progressDialog.setMessage("Registering Please Wait...");
        progressDialog.show();

        //creating a new user
        firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                        //checking if success
                        if(task.isSuccessful()){

                            String user_id = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                            UserInformation userInformation = new UserInformation(username, halls, levels, downloadUrl);


                            databaseReference.child(sexs).child(user_id).setValue(userInformation);


                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Successfully registered",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            //finish();
                            //startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Users.class));
                        }else{
                            //display some message here
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Registration Error",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });

    }
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the get url method is asynchronous. There should be a completion listener for when you actually sync and receive the url. Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38424203/firebase-storage-getting-image-url

Comment: Can you help? @Frank van Puffelen