# How to send image from firebase storage to Microsoft Emotion API (Cognitive Service)

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-storage, azure-cognitive-services

I am storing images uploaded on the application on firebase storage. I then need to retrieve the image and send it to Microsoft's Cognitive Service (emotion API). I tried sending the download URL of an image to the API but it doesn't take - it gives me a 400 error. How can I send an image from firebase storage to the Emotion API.

Below, is the code that stores the uploaded file to firebase storage... I need to continue the code at the end of this code snippet.

```
 download_photo_btn.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    var uid;

    if (user != null) {
    uid = user.uid;  // The user's ID, unique to the Firebase project. Do NOT use
                     // this value to authenticate with your backend server, if
                     // you have one. Use User.getToken() instead.
    }
    var snap = takeSnapshot();
    var blob = dataURItoBlob(snap);

    // Create a root reference
    var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();

    // Initial UID for images
    var selfieID = 0;

    // Create a reference to 'mountains.jpg'
    var selfieRef = storageRef.child(uid + '-' + selfieID++ + '.png');

    // Create a reference to 'images/mountains.jpg'
    var selfieImagesRef = storageRef.child('/selfies/' + uid  + '-' + selfieID++ + '.png');


    // While the file names are the same, the references point to different files
    selfieRef.name === selfieImagesRef.name            // true
    selfieRef.fullPath === selfieImagesRef.fullPath    // false

    // send image file to firebase storage
    var file = blob; 
    var uploadTask = selfieImagesRef.put(file);
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options:

- Since you already have it handy, you can upload the same `blob` to the Emotion API.  This does mean    that you will upload your image data twice, once to Firebase and once    to Microsoft.
- You can get a public URL for your storage item. [This](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files) is the relevant documentation.  Note that you may need to [adjust the permission](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/start#sample-rules) of your storage for Cognitive Services to access the image.

Some additional info here: [firebase storage - getting image URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38424203/firebase-storage-getting-image-url)