# android firebase storage retrieve in listview

Tags: android, listview, firebase, firebase-storage

Suppose I have 5 audio files in Firebase Storage and I want to retrieve those 5 audio files and display them in a list view. As I click on any of 5 files then they should be downloaded to local phone memory?

Comment: just not able to display in list view..

Comment: can you show your data strucutre

Comment: What you are asking for now is a request forsomeone to do everything. Edit the post and show us what you have tried. So we can guide you.

Comment: There is no API to retrieve a list of the files in Firebase Storage. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37335102/how-to-get-an-array-with-all-pictures/37337436#37337436

Comment: Thanks Frank van Puffelen.. Will use Database for storing file details. Now able to solve the problem..

Answer (score 0):

Get the list of your 5 songs on your refernece.then add this list to adapter

```
            your_ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener()     {
             @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


            songslist= new ArrayList<String>();

            Toast.makeText(DataFromFirebase.this, "number of songs are " + dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //String value = (String) dataSnapshot.getValue();
                sizetemp=dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
            // Result will be holded Here
            for (DataSnapshot dsp : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                songslist.add(String.valueOf(dsp.getKey())); //add result into array list

            //NOW YOU HAVE ARRAYLIST WHICH HOLD RESULTS




        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError firebaseError) {

        }


    });
```