# when ever I use firebase method to retrieve download url from firebase storage, it returns this format "com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu@41f55k88"

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

whenever i use this method to retrieve stored image url in firebase storage
`taskSnapshot.getMetadata().getReference().getDownloadUrl().toString();`
I expect that this method will return the download url of saved image, but what it returns is something with this format `com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu@41f55k88`
here is firebase database tree
[image]
here is my code snippet.

```
final StorageReference filePath = userProfileImageRef.child(currentUserID + ".jpg");
            filePath.putFile(resultUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    final String downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getMetadata().getReference().getDownloadUrl().toString();
                    Log.d("url", downloadUrl);
                    usersRef.child("profileimage").setValue(downloadUrl).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                Toast.makeText(SetupActivity.this, "Image stored", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            } else {
                                String message = task.getException().getMessage();
                                Toast.makeText(SetupActivity.this, "Error: " + message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
```

Comment: you could save the link when you upload the file/image to the storage for later use.

Comment: add the firebase tree too

Comment: if you mean firebase database tree, I updated the question with an image of my firebase database tree.

Comment: @M.Moustafa so you are saving the image url in the database and want to retrieve it to access the image located in the storage?

Comment: yes that is exactly what i am doing, but sadly i can't retrieve the download link I only retrieve this format "com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu@41f55k88"

Comment: @M.Moustafa check my answer and see if resolves your problem

Answer (score 1):

try to use this method

```
 filepath.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {

                           final String downloadUrl = 
                           uri.toString();
                     }
                     });
```

so it will be

```
    final StorageReference filePath = userProfileImageRef.child(currentUserID + ".jpg");
                filePath.putFile(resultUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                      filepath.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {

                               final String downloadUrl = 
                               uri.toString();
                         }
                         });
                    }


                        usersRef.child("profileimage").setValue(downloadUrl).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    Toast.makeText(SetupActivity.this, "Image stored", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                } else {
                                    String message = task.getException().getMessage();
                                    Toast.makeText(SetupActivity.this, "Error: " + message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
```

Comment: gave me the same result not the download url

Comment: @M.Moustafa try the new solution, I have edited the commint

Comment: not working also.

Comment: after editing your answer it is working now, just add `usersRef.child("profileimage").setValue(downloadUrl).addOncompletelistener()` method to the focus of the method `onSuccess(Uri uri){}` edit ur answer and i will mark it as the right answer

Comment: Glad to hear that!. I edited it

Answer (score 0):

To do what you want i would do something like this:

I am gonna assume you have a Uri with the image path lets call it: `filepath`  then:

```
final String filename = filepath.getPath().substring(filepath.getPath().lastIndexOf("/")+1);
final StorageReference storagePath = mStorageRef.child("imagens/").child(filename);

storagePath.putFile(filepath).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
        storagePath.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(uri.toString(), filename);
                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("The path in your database").push().setValue(fileInfo);
                Toast.makeText(UploadActivity.this, "Upload done", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(UploadActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

The `onSuccess` method has the uri that you want, i am saving it in a class `FileInfo`.

After the upload is done and the information about the file uploaded is stored in the database you retrieve the information like this:

```
mFirebaseInstance = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
mDatabase = mFirebaseInstance.getReference("The path in your database");
mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        filesList.clear();
        for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            FileInfo fileInfo = dataSnapshot1.getValue(FileInfo.class);
                filesList.add(fileInfo);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        //Handle the mehtod in your way
    }
});
```

In the above code i am retrieving from the database all the "nodes" under the given path you give it, for the case you have more then 1 image that you would like to get the url and i am saving the content in my `FileInfo` class that looks like this:

```
import android.net.Uri;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class FileInfo implements Serializable{

    String filename, downloadURL;

    public FileInfo(){
    }

    public FileInfo(String downloadURL, String filename) {
        this.downloadURL = downloadURL;
        this.filename = filename;
    }

    public String getDownloadURL() {
        return downloadURL;
    }

    public void setDownloadURL(String downloadURL) {
        this.downloadURL = downloadURL;
    }

    public String getFilename() {
        return filename;
    }

    public void setFilename(String filename) {
        this.filename = filename;
    }
}
```

Firebase using the Serialize implementation does the job of filling the class for you with the content that exist in each "node" of the database.

Note: you dont need the class but i think it fits your problem better since you save more than just the image url in the dabase that way you can adapt the class to your needs