# How to get list of Images stored in Firebase storage in android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I am trying to get list of images stored in Firebase storage. I have created a folder named "images". Now i am trying to get all images those exist there. So please tell me how can i do this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You cant. you have to store the "downloadUrl", or the specific storage location of each image in the Database, and then retrieve it from there.

Comment: Check this already answered question
[How to get an array with all pictures?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37337436/5932049)

Comment: I have seen this answer but not found any solution.

Comment: There is no API to get a list of images from Firebase Storage. You'll need to store the list elsewhere, such as in the Firebase Database. If you're having trouble making this work, share the [minimal code that reproduces where you are stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thanks @FrankvanPuffelen for your answer