# How to get the directory content length of firebase directory

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

How to get the firebase directory size in Android. I want get the count of firebase directory elements in Android.

Comment: What directory size? Your question is very confusing !

Comment: Suppose, If I have 5 image files in Firebase directory. Then How can I get this 5 number pragmatically?

Comment: There is no Firebase API to get a list of the files in a Firebase Storage folder.  See this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37337436/4815718.