# Externally link to files stored on Firebase Storage?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

Is there any way possible to get a direct URL to download the media file which I have uploaded onto the Firebase storage using my Android app?.

1. Scenario 1 :- I am basically looking for a http or a https URL which I can paste it in the browser and the image can be downloaded.
2. Scenario 2:- I can get a public url so that I can write a download manager in my web app which can download the images from these urls.

Also, If possible I want it to be completely independent of any reference of firebase database.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Once you have a reference to a file in Firebase Storage, you can [get its download URL](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files#download_data_via_url), which is a publicly accessible but unguessable URL for that file. There is no API to get a listing of the files in Firebase Storage. You seem to already know that, so what makes your question different from [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37335102/how-to-get-an-array-with-all-pictures)?

Answer (score 3):

When you upload the file, a URL for the stored file is available in the returned [UploadTask.TaskSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/storage/UploadTask.TaskSnapshot).  You can also obtain the URL from a `StorageReference` using [getDownLoadUrl()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/storage/StorageReference.html#getDownloadUrl()).

An [example can be found](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/storage/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/firebasestorage/MyUploadService.java#L86-L102) in the Firebase Quickstart project.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Fibrebase SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/start) on your server-side to [download](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files) any stored file to serve it when a client requests it by name for example.