# Android: Check the number of images stored in a folder in firebase storage

Tags: android, arrays, firebase-storage

I want to check the number of images stored  firebase storage

Did check the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/storage/StorageReference) but didn't find anything useful using the storage reference.

I actually need to get an array of images. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38978236/6393561) answer that explains the problem but it is in swift and the functions seem to be different as well. Anyone who could explain how to do this is Java?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get an array with all pictures?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37335102/how-to-get-an-array-with-all-pictures)

Comment: See Zero to App (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xAsvwy1-oxE) and Java source (https://gist.github.com/puf/f49a1b07e92952b44f2dc36d9af04e3c)