# How to download entire folder from Firebase Storage?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage

I want to download an entire folder from Firebase storage. I can download single files using `DownloadURL` as follows, but it does not work for folders.

```
var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();

// Create a reference to the file we want to download
var starsRef = storageRef.child(path);

// Get the download URL
starsRef.getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {
  // Insert url into an <img> tag to "download"
  ImageUrl = url;

  console.log(ImageUrl);
}).catch(function(error) {
  switch (error.code) {
    case 'storage/object_not_found':
      // File doesn't exist
      break;

    case 'storage/unauthorized':
      // User doesn't have permission to access the object
      break;

    case 'storage/canceled':
      // User canceled the upload
      break;

    case 'storage/unknown':
      // Unknown error occurred, inspect the server response
      break;
  }
});
```

How to download entire folder from Firebase?

Comment: Question on what you expect the intended behavior to be: an array of all files, a zipped folder containing all files, or something else?

Comment: @MikeMcDonald I want to download a zipped folder containing all files.

Comment: Here is an elegant solution that will solve all your problems, download all files at once as a single .zip file right on the client side: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66732338/8138591 (March 21, 2021)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no API in Firebase Storage to download all files in a folder. You will have to download the files one by one, or create a zip file that contains all the files.

As [Lahiru's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52633416/209103) shows it *can* be accomplished with `gsutils`, but that's a server-side operation - not something you'd run in your client-side application.

Related:

- [How to get a list of all files in Cloud Storage in a Firebase app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37335102/how-to-get-an-array-with-all-pictures)

Comment: I cannot find the way to get all the files and create a zip file from above related links. Please give me some tips to find a way to create a zip file that contains all the files. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 96):

You can use [gsutil](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp) to download the whole storage bucket

```
gsutil -m cp -R gs://<bucket_name> .
```

Comment: easiest solution!

Comment: This worked well. Installing `gsutil` was the most time-consuming part.

Comment: Don't forget to enter the destination URL after the gsutil command like so: `gsutil cp -r gs://<bucket_name>.appspot.com Downloads` The destination URL must name a directory, bucket, or bucket subdirectory.

Comment: One thing that tripped me up for a bit was I forgot to add the `.` at the end in the answer above. That `.` is important :)

Comment: refer to [this](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil_install#debian-and-ubuntu) for installing gsutil

Comment: Thanks, this saved my life. I accidentally deleted files which were only there in my firebase storage.

Comment: But, this is system-level installation right? how to archive it via Node APIs?

Comment: Btw in windows you should run the shell in administrator to not get `Access Denied`

Comment: Appending folder name after the bucket url also works (if you want to download only one particular folder).

Comment: Is it possible to run that from the backend Admin SDK?

Answer (score 6):

Command **gustil** for **Windows** !!!

```
gsutil cp -r gs://<bucket_name>.appspot.com/OBJECT_NAME "D:\path"
```

Use Cloud tools for PowerShell

REF for install windows >> https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil_install

Comment: gsutil is also available for Mac, terminal command is same as above (change dest. path!)...   https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil_install#mac

Answer (score 3):

You can download the folder by creating a zip file of it.

Here is a sample function:

```
import JSZip from 'jszip';
import { saveAs } from 'file-saver';
import {
  getStorage,
  listAll,
  ref,
  getDownloadURL,
  getMetadata,
} from 'firebase/storage';
import { auth } from '../../Firebase';

export const downloadFolderAsZip = async () => {
  const jszip = new JSZip();
  const storage = getStorage();
  const folderRef = ref(
    storage,
    'images'
  );
  const folder = await listAll(folderRef);
  const promises = folder.items
    .map(async (item) => {
      const file = await getMetadata(item);
      const fileRef = ref(storage, item.fullPath);
      const fileBlob = await getDownloadURL(fileRef).then((url) => {
        return fetch(url).then((response) => response.blob());
      });
      jszip.file(file.name, fileBlob);
    })
    .reduce((acc, curr) => acc.then(() => curr), Promise.resolve());
  await promises;
  const blob = await jszip.generateAsync({ type: 'blob' });
  saveAs(blob, 'download.zip');
};
```

Comment: This solution is absolutely great, thank you very much!

Comment: glad it helped took me a couple hours to figure it out

Comment: Thanks! You don't probably don't need to call `await getMetadata()` for the name - `item.name` in place of `file.name` should work.

Answer (score 0):

For a recursive solution that includes subfolders in the zip file, see the following sample. You'll instantiate a jszip object, await promises from a function that zips files and traverses the directories, then save the zip. If the content is a file ("item"), it is zipped into the jszip object. If it is a folder ("prefix"), the function is called again with a new subpath, passing in the same jszip object. For further improvement, you may want to get contents with `list` and pagination if your contents are too many for `listAll`, since `listAll` limits retrievals.

```
import JSZip from 'jszip';
import { saveAs } from 'file-saver';
import {
  getStorage, ref, getBlob, listAll,
} from "firebase/storage";

const addFilesFromDirectoryToZip = async (directoryPath = "", zip) => {
  const storage = getStorage();
 
  const directoryContentsRef = ref(
    storage,
    directoryPath
  );
  const directoryContents = await listAll(directoryContentsRef);

  for (const file of directoryContents.items) {
    const fileRef = ref(storage, file.fullPath);
    const fileBlob = await getBlob(fileRef)
    zip.file(file.fullPath, fileBlob);
  }

  for (const folder of directoryContents.prefixes) {
    await addFilesFromDirectoryToZip(folder.fullPath, zip);
  };
};

export const downloadFolderAsZip = async (directoryPath = "") => {
  const zip = new JSZip();

  await addFilesFromDirectoryToZip(directoryPath, zip);

  const blob = await zip.generateAsync({ type: "blob" });
  const name = directoryPath.split('/').pop();
  saveAs(blob, name);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Following the suggestions above, I made the .html script.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Download Firebase Storage Folder</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Download Firebase Storage Folder</h1>

  <button id="downloadButton">Download Folder</button>

  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-storage.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.7.1/jszip.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/FileSaver.js/2.0.5/FileSaver.min.js"></script>

  <script>
    // Initialize Firebase with your configuration
    const firebaseConfig = {
            apiKey: 'apiKey....', //replace
            authDomain: 'YOUR_AUTH_DOMAIN',
            projectId: 'YOUR_PROJECT_ID',
            storageBucket: 'YOUR_STORAGE_BUCKET',
            messagingSenderId: 'YOUR_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID',
            appId: 'YOUR_APP_ID',
    };

    // Initialize Firebase
    const app = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

    // Define the downloadFolderAsZip function here
    const downloadFolderAsZip = async () => {
      console.log("Starting folder download...");

      const jszip = new JSZip();
      const storage = firebase.storage(app);
      const folderName = '/[Your folder name]'; //Your folder name 

      try {
        const folderRef = storage.ref(folderName);
        console.log("Folder reference created:", folderRef);

        const downloadFiles = async (folderRef, path) => {
          const folder = await storage.ref(folderRef.fullPath).listAll();
          console.log("Folder:", path);
          console.log("Files in the folder:", folder.items);

          const promises = folder.items.map(async (item) => {
            console.log("Downloading file:", item.name);
            const file = await item.getMetadata();
            const fileRef = storage.ref(item.fullPath);
            const fileBlob = await fileRef.getDownloadURL().then((url) => {
              return fetch(url).then((response) => {
                if (!response.ok) {
                  console.error("Failed to fetch file:", item.name);
                  throw new Error('Failed to fetch file');
                }
                return response.blob();
              });
            });
            jszip.folder(path).file(item.name, fileBlob);
          });

          await Promise.all(promises);

          for (const subfolder of folder.prefixes) {
            await downloadFiles(subfolder, `${path}${subfolder.name}/`);
          }
        };

        await downloadFiles(folderRef, '');

        console.log("Number of files added to the ZIP:", jszip.files.length);

        if (jszip.files.length === 0) {
          console.log("ZIP is empty.");
          return;
        }

        const blob = await jszip.generateAsync({ type: 'blob' });
        saveAs(blob, 'download.zip');
        console.log("Download completed.");
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error:', error);
        alert('An error occurred while downloading the folder.');
      }
    };

    // Add an event listener to the "Download Folder" button
    const downloadButton = document.getElementById('downloadButton');
    downloadButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
      downloadFolderAsZip();
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

1. Fill the credentials
2. Fill the folder name
3. Save
4. Open the .html file with the browser
5. Be happy

Comment: This give error in folder name, can you help me to solve error

Answer (score 0):

The `gcloud` CLI is now recommended over `gsutil`.
Use the following command to download an entire bucket:

```bash
gcloud storage cp "bucket path" . -r
```

Docs: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/storage/cp

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with Firebase Storage, it's recommended to use the [gcloud storage commands](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/discover-object-storage-gcloud) (instead of `gsutil`)

> Important: gsutil is not the recommended CLI for Cloud Storage. Use gcloud storage commands in the Google Cloud CLI instead. [ref](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp)

Here's a page with some useful examples on how to use the CLI

In order to copy all files in a folder to a different folder, we can use the `[--recursive, -R, -r]` flag with the `cp` command:

```bash
gcloud storage cp --recursive fromDir toDir
```

For example:

```bash
gcloud storage cp --recursive gs://my-bucket-name.appspot.com/myFromFolder gs://my-bucket-name.appspot.com/myToFolder
```