# how to differentiate between images in storage in Firebase android?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I need to upload multiple images related to multiple things 
for example images for users images for categories and etc ...

when I searched about uploading images in Firebase they are upload them in Storage but if I want for example to retrieve all users images how can I do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll typically want to store the images from each user in a separate folder, so that you can [secure access](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/user-security#user_private) to it. So:

```
/uid1/image1
/uid1/image2
/uid2/image3
/uid2/image4
```

But even with that structure you can't get a list of the files from the Firebase SDK for Cloud Storage. See these questions for more on that:

- [How to get a list of all files in Cloud Storage in a Firebase app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37335102/how-to-get-a-list-of-all-files-in-cloud-storage-in-a-firebase-app)
- [How to download entire folder from Firebase Storage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41461337/how-to-download-entire-folder-from-firebase-storage)
  *

So you'll typically want to store the path and/or download URL for each image in a separate location too. The Firebase Realtime Database and Cloud Firestore are great for that. If you store them in a similar structur as the files in Storage, it'll be easy to query for just the images of a specific user.