# Firebase storage - Download directory as ".zip"

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

If you use firebase storage, you could see it's not possible to download a folder (as zip) directly from `firebase UI` or using `gcloud UI`. So it can be hard to create backup of your `firebase storage` bucket, moreover if you use `firestore` you can export collections into `firebase storage`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52633416/5766054

Answer (score 4):

I created a `nodejs` script based on `firebase-admin` and `jszip`, with two args : first the download  `path` in `firebase storage` and second is the  path where stored the `zip` file

package.json:

```json
{
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^9.6.0",
    "jszip": "^3.6.0"
  }
}
```

index.js:

```js
const fs = require("fs");
const JSZip = require('jszip');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

const serviceAccount = require("./service-account-key.json");

async function main (){
    try{
        admin.initializeApp({
            credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
            storageBucket: "stackd-56e96.appspot.com",
        });
        const bucket = admin.storage().bucket();

        const src_storage_path = process.argv[2];
        let dest_storage_path = process.argv[3];

        if(dest_storage_path.includes(":"))
            dest_storage_path = dest_storage_path.replace(":", "_")

        const jszip = new JSZip();
        const files = (await bucket.getFiles({
            prefix: `${src_storage_path}/`
        }))[0]

        const filesContent = await Promise.all(
            files.map(file => file.download())
        );

        filesContent.forEach((content, i) => {
            jszip.file(files[i].name, content[0])
        });

        const content = await jszip.generateAsync({ type: 'nodebuffer' });

        await fs.promises.writeFile(dest_storage_path, content)
    } catch (error){
        console.error(error)
    }
}

main();
```

command line exemple:

`node index.js 2021-04-16T11:47:46_54052 backup.zip`

[image]