# Firebase Storage gs url to http

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage, firebase-console

I downloaded a Unity project that use images stored in Firebase server using the following link:
https://zplayer360-86b30.firebaseapp.com

Now I want to reproduce this with my own file. I created a Firebase project using Firebase Console, uploaded manually the images, but now I click "copy folder url" button and it provide me only this link:
gs://insidehome-29c9e.appspot.com/

I need a free HTTP public link. 
How can I obtain this?

Answer (score 26):

When you upload a file to Firebase Storage, it automatically gets:

- a Google Storage URL (starting with `gs://`), which you can use to access the file through the Firebase Storage SDK and the Google Storage API.
- a download URL (starting with `https://`), which is a publicly-readable-but-non-guessable URL that you can use to download the URL with regular HTTP clients

What you're looking for is the second URL, which you can find in the [Firebase Storage console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/storage/files/) when you select a file:
[image]

At the bottom right you can see the download URLs for the file. One of these is auto-created when you upload the file, but you can create more of them or revoke existing ones.

I am not entirely sure what you mean by "free" URL. The link is publicly readable, but downloads will count against your Firebase Storage download quota of course.

Comment: Thank you. But I don't need the URL of a single file but of an entire storage folder. Can you help me?

Comment: There is no way in Firebase Storage to access folder. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37335102/how-to-get-an-array-with-all-pictures/37337436#37337436

Comment: I was looking just for the download url. After manually upload an image to storage from the firebase console, if you click the little blue "open image in a new window" icon, it will open a new tab with the image, and the https image download url will be in the url bar

Answer (score 13):

If there are no rules on Firebase storage. You are not protected.

Then it's publicly-readable-and-guessable, One can convert `gs://` URL to `https://` to download any file without Google SDK's.

https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/[projectID].appspot.com/o/[folderName]%2F[fileName]

**Google Storage URL**

gs://invitepeople-5d38c.appspot.com/profilePhotos/profile_1.jpg

**Https downloadable URL**

https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/invitepeople-5d38c.appspot.com/o/profilePhotos%2Fprofile_1.jpg?alt=media

Don't guess profile_2.jpg :)

Comment: Yeah guessing can cause issues better to be secure in your data storage part especially