# Unable to load image from Firebase Storage using Flutter Image Network

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I created dummy list of items in my Firestore and stored an image in my storage.

Here's my code for reading the Image form
child: ListView.separated(

```
              itemBuilder: (context, int index) {
                return ListTile(
                  leading: Image.network(
                    itemNotifier.itemList[index].imageURL),
                    width: 100.0,
                    height: 100.0,
                  ),
                  title: Text('${itemNotifier.itemList[index].name}'),
                  subtitle: Text(
                    '${itemNotifier.itemList[index].description}',
                    maxLines: 2,
                  ),
                  trailing: Text(
                    '${itemNotifier.itemList[index].price.toString()}',
                  ),
                );
```

The error I get when I try viewing this items List page is as below:

════════ Exception caught by image resource service ════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following NetworkImageLoadException was thrown resolving an image codec:
HTTP request failed, statusCode: 404, http://(db-name).appspot.com/images/pablo-downloading.png

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#0      NetworkImage._loadAsync (package:flutter/src/painting/_network_image_io.dart:95:9)

#1      NetworkImage.load (package:flutter/src/painting/_network_image_io.dart:48:14)
#2      ImageProvider.resolveStreamForKey. (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:501:13)
#3      ImageCache.putIfAbsent (package:flutter/src/painting/image_cache.dart:359:22)
...
Image provider: NetworkImage("http://(db-name).appspot.com/images/pablo-downloading.png", scale: 1.0)
Image key: NetworkImage("http://(db-name).appspot.com/images/pablo-downloading.png", scale: 1.0)
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

What could I be missing here? Is it normal to have the String for the image url to start with "**gs://**"? Do I have to encode and decode for reads and writes each time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there are two urls generated for every image you upload to firebase storage

1. storage url (starting with gs://)
2. download url (starting with https://)

you need to use the download url

to get the download url in flutter you can refer the following block of code
StorageReference

```
firebaseStorageRef=FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child('fileName');   
var url = await firebaseStorageRef.getDownloadURL();
```

to get the download link from firebase storage UI console click on the image , a left dialog wil appear and right click on the blue underlined image name and click opean in new tab
[image]

reference
https://stackoverflow.com/a/41767410/11330119

Comment: This is my current rules for storage.

Comment: Is it normal to have the String for the image url to start with gs://? Do I have to encode and decode for reads and writes each time?

Comment: how are you getting the image links from firebase storage 
in flutter to get image link you can use the following code snippet
`StorageReference firebaseStorageRef =FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child('fileName');
  url = await firebaseStorageRef.getDownloadURL();`

Comment: sample firebase storage image link
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/b/bucket/o/images%20stars.jpg

Comment: Here's my getter method that I use to read from DB.

I also tried replacing the String url for my image with the link you sent above and it's still the same thing. 

getItems(ItemNotifier itemNotifier) async {
    QuerySnapshot snapshot = await itemCollection.getDocuments();

    List<Item> _itemList = [];

    snapshot.documents.forEach((document) {
      Item item = Item.fromMap(document.data);
      _itemList.add(item);
    });

    itemNotifier.itemList = _itemList;
  }

Comment: I think the issue is with how my image is saved when I manually upload on Firestore. Instead of a http:// or https:// it starts with gs://<my_db_name_and_unique_key>/appspot.com/image.jpg

Is this normal? Should I be using a special encoder/decoder to resolve this?

Comment: i have edited my answer check it out, i hope it helps.
The problem is you are using the storage link insted of download link, also the sample url which i gave was just to give an idea of how url formate looks like, the sample link is dead.

Comment: my pleasure, keep coding glhf.