# Failed to load network image

Tags: flutter, dart, url, firebase-storage, flutter-web

Im creating a flutter web app and my app wont display images from FirebaseStorage specifically. I get the correct download URL from firebasestorage but NetworkImage and Image.network wont display the image, but can display other image links.

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65653801/flutter-web-cant-load-network-image-from-another-domain

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41767410/1318946

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous ways to resolve this issue:

Configure your data for [CORS](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/web-images#cross-origin-resource-sharing-cors), excerpted from this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65653801/flutter-web-cant-load-network-image-from-another-domain):

> 1. Open the [GCP console](https://console.cloud.google.com/), select your project and start a cloud terminal session by clicking the `>_`
>    icon button in the top navbar.
> 2. Click the open editor button (pencil icon), then create the `cors.json` file. The `cors.json` file should look like this:

```
[
  {
    "origin": ["*"],
    "method": ["GET"],
    "maxAgeSeconds": 3600
  }
]
```

> I set the origin to `*` which means that every website can display your images. But you can also
> insert the domain of your website there to restrict access.
>
> 3. Run gsutil cors set `cors.json gs://your-bucket`

Other option is using html renderer:

> `flutter build web --release --web-renderer html`
>
> or
>
> `flutter run --web-renderer html`

Lastly is by using the package [image_network](https://pub.dev/packages/image_network) instead of flutter's NetworkImage.

> It allows you to render images on the web using CanvasKit without
> having problems with CORS.