# How do you reference images contained in a folder in the Firebase storage and display them in a recycler view

Tags: android, firebase

I'm trying to get a reference to images stored within a folder in firebase Storage,with text(which are stored in Firebase Database) on a card view stored and display them on a recycler view. please i hope this is well asked as it is my first question on stackoverflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it sounds like your not stuck on a particular problem just need general help getting started with this complex project. (this is what stack hates and why you got down-voted.)

you need to take this step by step:

first follow a tutorial on how to make card with a recycler view unless you already did that.

then learn how to access data from Firebase storage and display them in a view

then im assuming you want to loop through the pictures without knowing there names. so you need to find the references in a loop like here [how-to-get-an-array-with-all-pictures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37335102/how-to-get-an-array-with-all-pictures)

Comment: i initially stored my images in a folder on firebase storage but i had difficulty accessing them so i got a suggestion to try something else which was using  [cloudinary] to store my images.  So now i only have to include the link to the images on Firebase storage but still its still not displaying on my recycler view. The error is " No Adapter attached skipping Layout"

Comment: that's right @Yehuda Clinton. i rechecked the code and discovered that i made a very silly mistake which was not attaching the adapter to the recycler view  after setting it up.