# Upload and download files from Firebase Storage

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm currently developing a school app and I wanted to know if there is a way to upload and display Firebase storage files (PDF, DOCX, etc) in a listview and implement download when clicked?

Comment: All sounds feasible. What's the problem?

Comment: i manually uploaded some pdf files to the firebase storage but don't know how to view them in a listview

Comment: Firebase Storage doesn't have a public API to list files. So you will have to keep that list somewhere else (e.g. in the Firebase Database). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37335102/how-to-get-an-array-with-all-pictures

Comment: thanks, lemme give this a try