# Number of images in Firebase Storage

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I want to get number of images in folder in Storage like in image below but I still didnt find the solution, please help me, I need it!!
Thanks

[image]

Comment: Duplicate.  See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37337436/4815718