# Get manually added files from Firebase Storage

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm working on an iOS app and trying out Firebase. I'll have some audio files to stream in the app so I'm looking to use Firebase Storage for this. These files will be manually added by a user. From most of the tutorials and examples I've seen, they are all based on files being uploaded to storage from the app and then downloaded based off of that. In my case there will be multiple folders made, each containing multiple audio files.

Am I able to download these files to use in my app via Firebase Storage?

Comment: See the [Firebase iOS documentation for downloading files](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/download-files). What specific part is giving you problems here?

Comment: Frank, it's getting multiple files from folders. There examples are based off of knowing what the file is already. I'd like to loop through each folder in storage, get the files, and add them to an array or dictionary that I can use in my app.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. There is no public API to get a list of files inside Cloud Storage from a Firebase client. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37335102/how-to-get-an-array-with-all-pictures