# How to get-download a list of images-files from Firebase storage

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I have a website that has cards in grid with image inside and title for example
[image]

and I want to get a list of images from firebase storage, the problem is if I store the same image file my other image files with the same image are broken,

How I can get a list of images from firebase storage.
Or what is the best way to store image file with combine firebase database my code to add new card is like this I store the image metadata download URL

```
const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();

for (let selectedFile of [(<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('image')).files[0]]){

  let path = `/${this.prosforesFolder}/${selectedFile.name}`;
  let iRef = storageRef.child(path);

  iRef.put(selectedFile).then((snapshot) => {

    prosfora.imageUrl = snapshot.downloadURL;
    prosfora.image = selectedFile.name;
    prosfora.path = path;
    // firebase.database().ref('/listings').push(listing);
    return this.prosfores.push(prosfora);
  });

}
```

but what I get is if I store 6 files with the same image file name only the last image can render the other 5 is broken

to get the images from fire base I just cal this function

```
// gets the list of ypiresies 
this.firebaseService.getProsfores().subscribe(prosfores => {

  this.prosfores = prosfores;

  if (prosfores.length > 0) {
    this.prosforesExist = true;
  } else {
    this.prosforesExist = false;
  }

  console.log(prosfores);

  // afto kanei hide to preloader
  $( ".preloader-wrapper" ).hide();

  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.gallery-expand').galleryExpand({
      // dynamicRouting : true
      // defaultColor: 'red'
      // fillScreen : 'true'
    });
  });

});
```

What I do wrong, there is any way that I can change the file name before I upload the file on firebase storage ???

like image.png
     image-v2.png
     image-v3.png

How I can do that ??

Any Help is gonna be welcome

Comment: try to save the image with  timestamp.

Comment: I recommend watching Zero to App (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xAsvwy1-oxE) and checking out it's source code (https://gist.github.com/puf/8f67d3376d80ed2d02670d20bfc4ec7d). Those show you how to upload files with unique names, sync them through the database, and display them in a list in an app.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get an array with all pictures?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37335102/how-to-get-an-array-with-all-pictures)

Answer (score 0):

As a starting point to your problem I can offer you to use listAll function to gather first all your images from database. Firebase place it in the website [List files with Cloud Storage on Web](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/list-files)
According to that base function you can move on to what you need by using ItemRefs under ListRef :

```
function AllImages() {
  const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
  // Create a reference for folder 'formimages'
  var listRef = storageRef.child("formimages");
  // Find all the prefixes and items.
  listRef
    .listAll()
    .then((res) => {
      res.prefixes.forEach((folderRef) => {
        // All the prefixes under listRef.
        // You may call listAll() recursively on them.
      });
      res.items.forEach((itemRef) => {
        // All the items under listRef.
        itemRef.getDownloadURL().then((url) => {
          imagesArray.push(url);
          console.log(imagesArray);
        });
      });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
    });
  // [END storage_list_all]
}
```