# TypeError: firebase.storage(...).ref(...).once is not a function during retrive the images from Firebase in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-storage

I have to retrieve all the image from Firebase in Angularjs but I got errors.

```js
//GET THE IMAGES FROM THE FIREBASE
$scope.getImages = function() {
  firebase.storage().ref('user/image').once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
    var value = snapshot.val();
  })
}
```

```html
<div class="pull-right">
    <input type="submit" name="sumbit" value="submit" ng-click="getImages()">
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: "There currently is no API call in Firebase Storage to list all files in a folder" see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37335102/how-to-get-an-array-with-all-pictures

Comment: Thank you sir...it is possible to get single image from storage?