# How to Retrieve videos from Firebase in app?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-docs, firebase-storage

I want to add videos in firebase storage and retrieve all upload videos in-app through recycler view with card view.

Please give some reference or source code for this.

I am trying this for uploading video in firebase it is successfully uploaded but I am unable to retrieve it.

Thanks in advance.

```
public class VideoUplod extends AppCompatActivity
{
    private static final int RC_PDF_PICKER = 2;
    private FirebaseStorage mFirebaseStorage;
    private StorageReference mChatPDFStorageReference;
    public static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 1;

    @Override


protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_video_uplod);

    VideoView videoView =(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.image);


    //Creating MediaController
    MediaController mediaController= new MediaController(this);
    mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);


    //specify the location of media file
    Uri uri=Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/media/1.mp4");

    //Setting MediaController and URI, then starting the videoView
    videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
    videoView.setVideoURI(uri);
    videoView.requestFocus();
    videoView.start();



    mFirebaseStorage =FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
    mChatPDFStorageReference = mFirebaseStorage.getReference().child("Video");

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.setType("video/*");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY, true);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"), RC_PDF_PICKER);
}
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // Sign-in succeeded, set up the UI
            Toast.makeText(this, "Signed in!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // Sign in was canceled by the user, finish the activity
            Toast.makeText(this, "Sign in canceled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
        }
        //for photo storage check
    } else if (requestCode == RC_PDF_PICKER && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();

        // Get a reference to store file at chat_photos/<FILENAME>

        StorageReference photoRef = mChatPDFStorageReference.child(selectedImageUri.getLastPathSegment());

        // Upload file to Firebase Storage

        photoRef.putFile(selectedImageUri)
                .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {

                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        // When the image has successfully uploaded, we get its download URL
                        @SuppressWarnings("VisibleForTests")   Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();

                        // Set the download URL to the message box so that the user can send it to the database
                    }
                });
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should post some code to show your efforts.

Comment: "Please give some reference or source code for this" - It doesn't work like that man

Comment: yes, I am adding my efforts so please now help me @SafanMomin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd take a look at:

- Zero to App ([video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xAsvwy1-oxE), [source](https://gist.github.com/puf/f49a1b07e92952b44f2dc36d9af04e3c))
- [How to get an array with all pictures?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37335102/how-to-get-an-array-with-all-pictures)
- [Firebase SDK for Cloud Storage docs](http://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files)

From the docs, it's pretty simple to download a file:

```
StorageReference videoRef = storageRef.child("videos/myvideo.mp4");

final long ONE_MEGABYTE = 1024 * 1024;
videoRef.getBytes(ONE_MEGABYTE).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<byte[]>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(byte[] bytes) {
        // Transform bytes to a video, play
    }
}).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
        // Handle any errors
    }
});
```