# Pulling data from Dataservice Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I am new to Firebase and I am trying to explore it. I already know i can make a reference to database and pull some data like: firstName, email etc. However, I have a function for uploading images to storage. I have a reference to storage but i cannot find function for storage similar to the one for database so i can pull images or their names: 
`DataService.instance.usersRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot: DataSnapshot) in   }`

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There is currently no way to list the files in Cloud Storage through the Firebase SDK. You'll have to store the list of file names/paths elsewhere. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37335102/how-to-get-an-array-with-all-pictures. Once you have the paths to the files, you can download each of them as shown here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/download-files

Comment: Thank you for the help. It's a bummer that there is no such functionality.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get an array with all pictures?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37335102/how-to-get-an-array-with-all-pictures)