# Get Download URL from Firebase Storage in Flutter

Tags: firebase, dart, firebase-storage, flutter

I'm currently exploring Flutter, I found there is an official Firebase Storage plugin in Flutter [firebase_storage](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/firebase_storage)
I have storage reference like this one:

```
final StorageReference ref = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child("default.png");
```

But there is no method to get download URL from that StorageReference.

Comment: How do you upload the image? I haven't seen a simple way to get a download path from a `StorageReference` yet. I think the Firebase Storage plugin is still missing some features to be able to do something like shown in https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files

Comment: As Gunter mentioned, there's no way get the download path before uploading the image in first place.

Comment: Why do you need it before?

Comment: I uploaded the image manually from firebase console. It just a few lines to wrap native firebase storage library to flutter platform channel. Well I've done it by extending current plugin to my own

Comment: This isn't implemented yet, but we're working on it. In the meantime pull requests are very welcome.

Comment: @CollinJackson Is there an issue I can subscribe to? How to I follow progress on this?

Comment: I sent a pull request for this https://github.com/flutter/plugins/pull/390/files

Answer (score 32):

If the above solution doesn't work, try this:

```
Future<String> uploadImage(var imageFile ) async {
    StorageReference ref = storage.ref().child("/photo.jpg");
    StorageUploadTask uploadTask = ref.putFile(imageFile);

    var dowurl = await (await uploadTask.onComplete).ref.getDownloadURL();
    url = dowurl.toString();

    return url; 
}
```

Comment: Now that's the correct way to do it. Thanks, mate, spent like two hours figuring out wtf!

Comment: The above way is now deprecated, check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64764390/7015400

Comment: Can you please check out my question if possible https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68351097/reading-firebase-storage-image-security-rules

Answer (score 11):

use url like this:

```
printUrl() async {
    StorageReference ref = 
        FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child("images/sky.jpg");
    String url = (await ref.getDownloadURL()).toString();
    print(url);
}
```

Answer (score 8):

**At latest version `firebase_storage: ^5.0.1` Approach should be like below:**

```
Reference reference = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child("SupportChatImages").child(fileName);

    UploadTask uploadTask =  reference.putFile(imageFile);

    uploadTask.whenComplete(() async{

      try{
        imageUrl = await reference.getDownloadURL();
      }catch(onError){
        print("Error");
      }

      print(imageUrl);

    });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer!

Comment: Hello, This works for 1 file, However I am not sure hot to make it working for a list of files. I need to do something like ``` Future<List<String>> _uploadFiles(List<PickedFile> files) async {``` in previous version it is working fine with StorageTaskSnapshot snapshot = await uploadTask.onComplete; because of "await" inside for loop.

Comment: This is the perfect solution

Answer (score 6):

I had Implemented a method to save your image with a timestamp and get the downloadable url.

```
Future<String>photoOption() async {
    try {
        DateTime now = new DateTime.now();
        var datestamp = new DateFormat("yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss");
        String currentdate = datestamp.format(now);
        File imageFile = await ImagePicker.pickImage();


        StorageReference ref = FirebaseStorage.instance
            .ref()
            .child("images")
            .child("$currentdate.jpg");
        StorageUploadTask uploadTask = ref.putFile(imageFile);

        Uri downloadUrl = (await uploadTask.future).downloadUrl;
        addUser.downloadablelink = downloadUrl.toString();

        downloadableUrl = downloadUrl.toString();

        print(downloadableUrl);

    } catch (error) {
        print(error);
    }

    return downloadableUrl;
}
```

Comment: if I want to downlaod all files from a folder, can I just provide the folder name?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37335102/how-to-get-a-list-of-all-files-in-cloud-storage-in-a-firebase-app

Comment: `put` is deprecated. Make use of `putFile` .

Comment: The getter 'future' isn't defined for the class 'StorageUploadTask

Answer (score 5):

**For firebase_storage: ^10.0.1**

Here is the code to get URL of Uploaded Image..

```
uploadImagetFirebase(String imagePath) async {
 await FirebaseStorage.instance
  .ref(imagePath)
  .putFile(File(imagePath))
  .then((taskSnapshot) {
print("task done");

// download url when it is uploaded
if (taskSnapshot.state == TaskState.success) {
  FirebaseStorage.instance
      .ref(imagePath)
      .getDownloadURL()
      .then((url) {
    print("Here is the URL of Image $url");
    return url;
  }).catchError((onError) {
    print("Got Error $onError");
  });
}
});
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer with the latest version, I was looking for something like this !

Answer (score 3):

```
Future<String> urlDownload(file) async {
var uuid = Uuid().v1();
StorageReference ref =
    FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child("post_$uuid.jpg");
StorageUploadTask uploadTask = ref.putFile(file);

String downloadUrl =
    await (await uploadTask.onComplete).ref.getDownloadURL();
return downloadUrl;}
```

Comment: You should consider adding text to explain the code in the answer

Answer (score 1):

He is my solution :

```
StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child("myfile"); 
StorageUploadTask uploadTask = storageReference.putFile(file);
uploadTask.onComplete.then((s){ 
   s.ref.getDownloadURL(); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

My Solution

```
Future mainprofile(File image) async {
    try {
      DateTime now = new DateTime.now();
      var datestamp = new DateFormat("yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss");
      String currentdate = datestamp.format(now);
      _firebaseStorageRef = FirebaseStorage.instance
          .ref()
          .child(userRepository.uid)
          .child('main')
          .child("$currentdate.jpg");
      StorageUploadTask uploadTask = _firebaseStorageRef.putFile(image);
      uploadTask.onComplete.then((onValue) async {
        _mainurl = (await _firebaseStorageRef.getDownloadURL()).toString();
      });
    } catch (error) {
      print(error);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I have tried many ways and this worked for me after many tries as Firebase Storage removing old methods. If anyone getting error of 404 Object not found Then the below code also solves that.

```
Future<String> uploadSingleImage(File file) async {
    //Set File Name
    String fileName = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString() +
        AuthRepository.getUser().uid +
        '.jpg';
    
    //Create Reference
    Reference reference = FirebaseStorage.instance
        .ref()
        .child('Single Post Images')
        .child(fileName);

    //Now We have to check the status of UploadTask
    UploadTask uploadTask = reference.putFile(file);
    
    String url;
    await uploadTask.whenComplete(() async {
      url = await uploadTask.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
    });
   
    return url;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 Future<String> downloadFromFirebase() async {
  // Create reference
    StorageReference ref = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child("default.png");
    String _myUrl = await ref.getDownloadURL();
    return _myUrl.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution

this part is how i get image from picker

```
 Future getImage() async {
  var image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);

  setState(() {
    _image = image;
      print('Image Path $_image');
  });
}
```

than i upload it

```
 Future uploadPic(BuildContext context) async {

  String fileName = basename(_image.path);
  StorageReference firebaseStorageRef = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(fileName);
  StorageUploadTask uploadTask = firebaseStorageRef.putFile(_image);
  StorageTaskSnapshot taskSnapshot = await uploadTask.onComplete;


  final String url = (await taskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL());
  print('URL Is $url');
}
```

hope it will help someone

Answer (score 0):

Here is my approach, to upload an image to **Firebase Storage** and get the **dowlad URL**

```
 var img_name=DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString()+".png";

 final StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child("images/profile/"+img_name);

 var upload= await storageReference.putFile(croppedFile);
 await upload.onComplete;

 var url=await storageReference.getDownloadURL();
 print(url.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution for latest firebase_storage 9.0.0  **

```
Future<void> _uploadImage() async {
if (_image != null) {
  final fileName = '${DateTime.now()}.jpeg';
  Reference reference = _firebaseStorage.ref('uploads/$fileName');
  TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot = await reference
      .putFile(_image!)
      .whenComplete(() => reference.getDownloadURL());

  print(taskSnapshot.ref.fullPath.toString());

  setState(() {
    _imageUploadState = ImageUploadState.done;
  });
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

For **firebase_storage: ^10.0.1**

```
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart' as firebase_storage;

String image = 'gs://ID.appspot.com/image/1026_800x800.jpg';

firebase_storage.FirebaseStorage.instance.refFromURL(image).getDownloadURL().then((url) async {
                  print(url);
                });
```

Will download something like this: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/ID.appspot.com/o/...

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
Future<String> uploadFile(XFile _file) async {
File file = File(_file.path);
try {
  var ref = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref('uploads/' + _file.name);
  var uploadTask = await ref.putFile(file);
  if (uploadTask.state == TaskState.success) {
    final url = await ref.getDownloadURL();
    return url;
  }
  return "0";
} catch (e) {
  print(e);
  return e.toString();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Future<String> uploadImage(imageFile) async {
Reference ref = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child('default.png');
UploadTask uploadTask = ref.putFile(imageFile);
final snapshot = await uploadTask.whenComplete(() => {});
final urlDownload = await snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
print("The url is here! $urlDownload");
return urlDownload;
```

}

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Comment: There is nothing in this answer that has not been posted years ago by the others.

Answer (score 0):

**My solution using Async/await syntax and newest Firebase Storage 2022**

```
Future<String> uploadFileToStorage(String path, File image) async {
    TaskSnapshot uploadTask = await _storageReference.child(path).putFile(image);

    String pathdownlaod = await uploadTask.ref.getDownloadURL();

    return pathdownlaod;
  }
```

Comment: Can't work. Does uploadTask have  ref props?

Answer (score 0):

**FIREBASE STORAGE: ^11.2.5**

```
  uploadPhotoToFirebase(File photo) async {
   try {
    String ref = 'images/img-${DateTime.now().toString()}.jpeg';
    final storageRef = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref();
    UploadTask uploadTask = storageRef.child(ref).putFile(
     photo
    );
    var url = await uploadTask.then((task) => task.ref.getDownloadURL());
  } on FirebaseException catch (e) {
    throw Exception('Erro no upload: ${e.code}');
 }
```

}