# how to get url from firebase storage to save in firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-storage

i'am still new in flutter and firebase. I want to ask on how to get the URL file from storage and save it in firestore?
this is the code to upload file.

```
Future uploadFile() async {
if (file == null) return;

final fileName = basename(file.path);
final destination = 'files/$fileName';

task = FirebaseApi.uploadFile(destination, file);
setState(() {});

if (task == null) return;

final snapshot = await task.whenComplete(() {});
final urlDownload = await snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();

print('Download-Link: $urlDownload');
```

}

[another related class with the upload file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qiFq3.png)

Comment: Hello, you already get the download URL in the code you shared. What did you try for saving it in Firestore?

Comment: i dont know how to store the url in the firestore

Comment: You should have a look at the [documentation](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#adding-documents) which details, among other, how to add a doc to a Firestore collection. The URL is just a string that you would add to a String field.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter: How Can I Get URL From Firebase Storage In Firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59160998/flutter-how-can-i-get-url-from-firebase-storage-in-firestore)