# How to insert firebase storage images inside firestore field

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I have a problem in my flutter app , and the problem is in the storage of firebase .
I have a collection with field called `avatar(String)`. It's value comes from an image link , so first i uploaded the images to firebase storage and i changed the rules to allow read .
so when i refresh the code i get this error.

```
═══════ Exception caught by image resource service ════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

The following ArgumentError was thrown resolving an image

```
codec:
Invalid argument(s): Unsupported scheme 'gs' in URI gs://pfe-2020-51d9c.appspot.com/Asperge/asperges%20(1).jpg
```

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:

```
#0      _HttpClient._openUrl (dart:_http/http_impl.dart:2278:9)
#1      _HttpClient.getUrl (dart:_http/http_impl.dart:2197:48)
#2      NetworkImage._loadAsync (package:flutter/src/painting/_network_image_io.dart:84:59)
#3      NetworkImage.load (package:flutter/src/painting/_network_image_io.dart:47:14)
#4      ImageProvider.resolve.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:327:17)
```

...
Image provider: NetworkImage("gs://pfe-2020-51d9c.appspot.com/Asperge/asperges (1).jpg", scale: 1.0)
Image key: NetworkImage("gs://pfe-2020-51d9c.appspot.com/Asperge/asperges (1).jpg", scale: 1.0)
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

And this is my dart code

===================================================================================================

```
 ClipRRect(
            child: Image.network(snapshot.data[index].data['avatar'],
            height: 100,
            width: 170,
            fit: BoxFit.fill,
            ),
               borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
            ),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the Google Storage (which start with gs://) to download URL (which start with https://)
You can find it under Firebase storage-> File location-> Access token
[image]

```
 ClipRRect(
        child: Image.network(snapshot.data?.docs[index]["Your_firebase_field"],
        height: 100,
        width: 170,
        fit: BoxFit.fill,
        ),
           borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
        ),
```

I used [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41767410/13161130) as a reference

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31362315)

Answer (score 2):

Flutter doesn't know how to deal with the URLs that Cloud Storage uses natively to describe the location of an uploaded file.  That "gs://" indicates a custom scheme used by Cloud Storage.  What you will need to do is provide a URL that Flutter does understand.

You can get an HTTPS download URL from an uploaded file by [using getDownloadUrl()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48435365/get-download-url-from-firebase-storage-in-flutter).  That's the URL you should feed to Flutter to download and display the image.

Comment: i didn't get it  , how can i implements the getDowloadUrl() in my code                                     here is my code:                                                                                                                     ClipRRect(
                                      child: Image.network(snapshot.data[index].data['avatar'],
                                        height: 100,
                                        fit: BoxFit.fill,
                                      ),
                                    ),

Comment: you can make it a method that you call on I suppose

Answer (score 0):

Open the image you stored in your storage on the browser. There is an open icon right under the image name.

[image]

Then copy the URL of the image from the newly opened tab and replace it on your database where you had the "gs://..." value, which I think is the avatar value.