# How to get a list of files in a Google Cloud Storage folder using Node.js?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-storage

Using `bucket.getFiles()` it is possible to get all the files in a bucket.

My bucket has thousands of files and I really only want to get metadata on the files in a particular folder.

The [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/1.3.x/Bucket#getFiles) is not clear on how to just get the files from a folder. Apparently [it is possible to limit the results](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/1.3.x/global#GetFilesRequest) with a `GetFilesRequest` but none of the options include a path or a folder, at least not explicitly.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There is an ability to specify a prefix of the required path in options, e.g.

```
async function readFiles () {
  const [files] = await bucket.getFiles({ prefix: 'users/user42'});
  console.log('Files:');
  files.forEach(file => {
    console.log(file.name);
  });
};
```

Now it's finally available on documentation (thanks @Wajahath for the update):
https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/Bucket.html#getFiles

Comment: if (!file.name.endsWith('/') ){
      console.log(file.name);
    }

Answer (score 15):

Google cloud storage doesn't have folders/sub directories. It is an illusion on top of the flat namespace. i.e what you see as sub directories are actually objects which has a "/" character in its name.

You can read more about how Google cloud storage subdirectories work at the following link https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/HowSubdirectoriesWork

So by setting the `prefix` parameter of `GetFilesRequest` to the sub directory name you are interested in will return the object you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If you have lots of files in your bucket, you might want to look into listing them as a stream, so data aren't held up in the memory during the query.

**`GetFiles`, lists everything in one shot:**

```
  admin.storage().bucket()
    .getFiles({ prefix: 'your-folder-name/', autoPaginate: false })
    .then((files) => {
      console.log(files);
    });
```

**`getFilesStream`, lists everything as a stream:**

```
  admin.storage().bucket()
    .getFilesStream({ prefix: 'your-folder-name/' })
    .on('error', console.error)
    .on('data', function (file) {
      console.log("received 'data' event");
      console.log(file.name);
    })
    .on('end', function () {
      console.log("received 'end' event");
    });
```

Full docs and examples: [link](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/latest/storage/bucket#_google_cloud_storage_Bucket_getFilesStream_member_1_)