# Cloud Functions Delete a Folder: TypeScript

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

My storage bucket `budget-32bfc` contain the following folders;
`--+ Folder1
--+ Folder2
--+ Folder3`

I want to **delete *Folder1*** from Cloud Functions.

**ATTEMPT 1:**

```js
gcs.bucket("budget-32bfc").file('Folder1').delete().then(() => {
        console.log("Folder Deleted");
    }).catch(function (error) {
        console.log("Error listing users:", error);
    });
```

**ATTEMPT 2:**

```js
admin.bucket("budget-32bfc").file('Folder1').delete().then(() => {
        console.log("Folder Deleted");
    }).catch(function (error) {
        console.log("Error listing users:", error);
    });
```

Both attempt gave me a `404 Error: 'No such object: budget-32bfc/Folder1'`.

How do I delete a folder??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no concept of a "folder" in Cloud Storage, it is merely part of the name of each file. So you will have to delete all files that start with `Folder1/`. Once you do that, the folder is also gone.

Also see:

- [How to get a list of files in a Google Cloud Storage folder using Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49684942/how-to-get-a-list-of-files-in-a-google-cloud-storage-folder-using-node-js) (on how to get a list of files in a folder using the Node.js for Cloud Storage)
- [How to get a list of all files in Cloud Storage in a Firebase app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37335102/how-to-get-a-list-of-all-files-in-cloud-storage-in-a-firebase-app) (the Firebase SDKs do not have an API to list files)

Answer (score 4):

Version 1.7.x has the following method which returns a Promise:

> deleteFiles(query, callback)

It will try to delete each file inside the specified folder (folders too). If the deletion of one file fails, the process is stopped. (use 'force: true' to override this behavior).

```
bucket.deleteFiles({
    prefix: `${userId}/images`
})
.catch( (err) => {
    console.log(`Failed to delete all images of user ${userId}`);
});
```

Official Documentation: [Storage - deleteFiles](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/1.7.x/Bucket#deleteFiles)

Another solution found here: [click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54089533/firebase-storage-how-to-delete-file-from-storage-with-node-js)

(Note: I cannot mark this thread as duplicate as I only have 13 rep points, please stop deleting my comment because others might need to see this, thank you)