# How to delete a file from firebase storage using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage

Hi I want to delete a file from firebase storage. My storage hierarchy is simple and looks like this. 
[image: Storage hierarchy]

I searched for the method on how to delete file from firebase storage i found this.

```
function deletingFile(fileName, file, b ) {
// Create a reference to the file to delete
// const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
var desertRef = firebase.storage().ref().child(fileName);

// Delete the file
desertRef.delete().then(function () {
alert('file deleted successfully');

 var delImg = firebase.database().ref('students').child(abc).once('value')
  .then(function (data) {
    data.val().file.set() = {};
  })

 $(b).parents('tr').remove();

     // File deleted successfully
 }).catch(function (error) {
        alert(error)
    // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
 });
} // function deleting file ended here
```

Now when I am calling this function the following error is obtained, I am unable to resolve what is wrong here. fileName == 'DailyEase Color Theme.txt'

[image: Error on calling this function]

Comment: I have uploaded both the images, but i don't know why they aren't being shown up.

Comment: There might be a potential duplicate here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54089533/firebase-storage-how-to-delete-file-from-storage-with-node-js