# Get Only The Top Level Objects of A Bucket

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-storage

My Question is similar to this one [how to get a list of files in a google cloud storage folder using node js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49684942/how-to-get-a-list-of-files-in-a-google-cloud-storage-folder-using-node-js).

Only I am trying to just get the top level objects. I am trying to follow along here [nodejs storage samples files.js](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-storage/blob/000d0929ced42a8457f81d46e2ff323182fa2023/samples/files.js#L50), and when I try different combinations of "prefix" and "deliminator" I am having a hard time just getting the top level objects. I have tried a prefix of "" with a deliminator of "/". I have tried a prefix of "/" with a deliminator of "/". I tried a prefix of "/" with no deliminator. Nothing seems to work to allow me to get just a list of the top level objects. I seem to always get all files in the entire bucket. Any ideas on what the correct parameters for prefix and deliminator that might work? Are there other options that I am not aware of that could help?

To be a little more specific, given the following blobs:

- folder1/file1.txt
- folder2/file2.txt

I just want

- folder1/
- folder2/

A couple of things I have tried:

prefix: "", deliminator: "", results:

- folder1/
- folder1/file1.txt
- folder2/
- folder2/file2.txt

prefix: "", deliminator: "/", results:

- No results...

Prefix: "/", deliminator: "", results:

- No results...

Prefix: "/", deliminator: "/", results:

- No results...

Prefix: "folder1/", deliminator: "", results:

- folder1/
- folder1/file1.txt

... as I would expect; however again I cannot figure out the right combination of prefix and deliminator to just get the two top object results that I want:

- folder1/
- folder2/

Comment: In your examples and when you say "nothing seems to work" ... what is the output received for each example?  A read of the docs seems to say that a prefix of "" and a delimiter of "/" might work ... what did you find?

Comment: thank you for your reply. I updated my OP with those additional details.

Answer (score 4):

I think that I finally found the answer. The answer is in a different site for their documentation. Specifically [this site](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/index.html), and [this page (for Bucket.getFiles())](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/Bucket.html#getFiles). Their example shows a call back that has (err, files, nextQuery, apiResponse) arguments. Which is strange because even this site doesn't mention nextQuery, and apiResponse as parameters for [GetFilesCallback](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/global.html#GetFilesCallback).

I do want to use async / await, and try / catch in my application so taking the code examples on the [getFiles](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/Bucket.html#getFiles) page, I was able to infer that I could get what I needed by doing this:

```
const [files, nextQuery, apiResponse] = await storage.bucket(bucketName).getFiles({autoPaginate: false, delimiter: "/", prefix: ""});
```

and then personally I found that the data within "apiResponse" to be much more useful than in files. What I was looking for was in `apiResponse.items`, and `apiResponse.prefixes`.

I am just pretty surprised that none of the documentation shows what that `apiResponse` is supposed to look like, nor does the GetFilesCallback page even show it as a possible parameter. In any case I was able to find what I was looking for. I think for my use case I will be using that `apiResponse` callback parameter more than the `files` parameter.

Comment: Thanks it worked. The folders were under apiResponse.prefixes