# Get a list of folders from Google Cloud Platform bucket using Node.js

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I would like to display all the folders from my Google Cloud Storage bucket on my Node.js app but there is only getFiles() function.

For example a folder named **/abc**, with 2 files in it **/a** & **/b**. I would like to only get **/abc/** and no **/abc/a** & **/abc/b**.

**app.js**

```
router.get('/', async(req, res) => {
  let bucketName = 'my-bucket'

  const storage = Storage();

  const [files] = await storage.bucket(bucketName).getFiles();
  let app = [];
  for (const file of files) {
    const [metadata] = await file.getMetadata();
    app.push(metadata);
  };
  res.render('views/list.ejs', {
    apps : app, 
  });
  });
```

Answer (score 6):

It's worth noting that like S3 on AWS. GCS does not have 'directories' but paths.

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/HowSubdirectoriesWork

You can access the file names from `.name` on the objects returned from GCS. And you can add a prefix to the `.getFiles()` call.

```
router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    const bucketName = 'my-bucket'

    const storage = Storage()

    const [files] = await storage.bucket(bucketName).getFiles({ prefix: '/abc'})
    const objectNames = files.map(file => file.name)

    res.render('views/list.ejs', {
        apps: objectNames,
    })
})
```

Comment: Yes, but it display the directory name + file name "abc/a"

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: Ok thanks! if i have a lot of different paths, what prefix should i put ?

Comment: Well you've asked to get the contents of things prefixed with `/abc` but you don't want to return `/abc/a` - This is not possible as the object "a" is prefixed with `/abc/`. Take a look at the documentation I've put in the answer.

Comment: If you want to emit a particular file or 'folder pass a `.getFiles({ delimiter: '/c' })`

Comment: if you wanted to further filter those files you would need to process these yourself

Answer (score 0):

"folders" (prefixes) are being returned as part of the getFiles result:

example based on [Get Only The Top Level Objects of A Bucket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58896117/get-only-the-top-level-objects-of-a-bucket/58903254#58903254)

```
const options = {
    prefix: "folder/",
    autoPaginate: false,
    delimiter: "/"
};

const [files, nextQuery, apiResponse] = await storage.bucket(bucketName).getFiles(options);
// folders should be in apiResponse.prefixes
console.log(apiResponse.prefixes)
```