# google gsutil limit ls to a given depth level

Tags: gsutil

I need to figure out what subfolders are present on a bucket in order to decide what path to sync.

```
ls -r gs://<my_bucket>/**
```

returns all files and folders and I have a tree depth of >10 there!!

How can I get the list of folders and subfolders only and until a final depth of lets say 3 as with the `find -maxdepth` argument?

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you rephrase your question and explain what you really want to do..it will help in troubleshooting the issue

Comment: I need to get the list of subfolders (not contained files) until a depth of three on the bucket to discover what names these folders have.
I do not want to download (rsync) the whole bucker but only relevant subfolders after I can get their names from a ls like command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/ls) there is no such command  mentioned to list the folders/subfolders using maximum depth in gsutil.

To get the [top level objects of a bucket using node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58903254/15774176), it can be done by API as mentioned :

```
`const [files, nextQuery, apiResponse] = await storage.bucket(bucketName).getFiles({autoPaginate: false, delimiter: "/", prefix: ""});`
```

For more information you can refer to the [link](https://superuser.com/q/1495690) and [github case](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/issues/920) where a similar issue has been discussed.

> This command is mentioned as a trick :
> `gsutil ls -l gs://bucket_name/folder_name | xargs -I{} gsutil du -sh {}`

> There's no --max-depth support in gsutil du. You could write a script that lists the first-level folder names, and then iterate over those folders and run `gsutil ls -l $folder/*`