# Saving filename in DB after uploading to GCP Storage or using bucket.getFiles()

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-platform, architecture, upload

I've been searching in StackOverflow, but it seems that this question has not been asked yet. It's an architecture question about files being uploaded to GCP Storage.

TL;DR : Is there any issue using bucket.getFiles() directly (from a server), rather than storing each filename in my db, and then asking for them one by one and returning the array to the client ?

**The situation:**

I’m working on a feature that will allow the user to upload image attachements linked to a delivery note. This delivery note can have multiple attachements.

I use a simple upload button on my client (mobile device), and upload the content in GCP in a `path/to/id-deliveryNote` folder such as: `path/to/id-deliveryNote/filename.jpg` `path/to/id-deliveryNote/filename2.jpg` etc…

Somewhere else in the app the user should be able to click and download on each of those attachements.

**The solution**

After the upload being done in GCP, I asked myself how to read those files and give the user a download link to the file. That’s when I found the: `bucket.getFiles()` function.

Since my path to files are all below the same `id-deliveryNote/` prefix, I leverage the usage of `bucket.getFiles(prefix)` and after the promise resolve can safely return to my user the list of links available.

**The issue**

I do not store the filenames in my deliveryNote table in my DB. Which can sound a bit problematic, relying on GCP to know the attachements of one deliveryNote. The way I see it is that, in my way I do not need to replicate the information in our DB (and possibly handling failure at two spots), and if I need those files I will at the ask GCP to give me their links. The opposed way of thinking is that, storing the names you will be able to list the attachements for the clients, and then generating the download link, when the user click a specific attachement.

My question is: Is there any issue using bucket.getFiles() directly (from a server), rather than storing each filename in my db, and then asking for them one by one and returning the array to the client ?

Some point that could influence the chosen method:

- GCP costs per call difference ?
- Invalid application data structure ?
- Other things ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no issue with using this method to return the link for the files to download. In the API documentation for this method - accessible [here](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/Bucket.html#getFiles) - they even show an example of returning files using prefixes as well. You just need to look out that Cloud Storage actually doesn't use real folders and only names that look like they are in folders - more details in this case [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49684942/how-to-get-a-list-of-files-in-a-google-cloud-storage-folder-using-node-js) - so you don't mix up concepts when working with names and prefixes.

For the pricing point, you can get the whole pricing for Google Cloud Storage in [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing), including how much each operation will cost - for example, it will cost you $ 0.02 per 50000 operations for object gets, retrieving bucket and object metadata - storing data, etc. After you check that, you can compare with your database costs as well, to check it if this point will impact you.

To summarize, there is no problem for you to follow this. The advantage of storing the names on Database, it's actually that even though you could have failure in two spots, it's more probable for you to face issues in only one place and this way the replication would be a great thing to have. So, you just need to decide which one fits you best.