# How to copy storage folder into a new one? (Cloud storage)

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, firebase-admin

I am trying to migrate data in storage from `documents/docId/file.name` to `users/userId/documents/docId/file.name`. Is it possible to copy folders like `documents/docId` without needing to define "file.name"?

My code currently only works when I provide the exact file name. It looks like this:

```
const updateStorageData = async () => {
  return admin
    .storage()
    .bucket()
    .file('documents/1/Screenshot 2023-05-09 at 00.33.45.png')
    .copy(
      admin
        .storage()
        .bucket()
        .file('users/testID/documents/1/Screenshot 2023-05-09 at 00.33.45.png'),
    );
};
```

I would like to try to copy all files in the folder without needing to provide the exact file name. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There no single API to copy all files in a folder, but you can [list the files in a folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49684942/how-to-get-a-list-of-files-in-a-google-cloud-storage-folder-using-node-js) and then copy them one-by-one in a loop.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [`getFiles()`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/Bucket.html#getFiles) and [`move()`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/File.html#move) methods along the following lines:

```
const getFilesResponse = await admin
    .storage()
    .bucket()
    .getFiles();
const arrayOfFiles = getFilesResponse[0];

const promises = [];
arrayOfFiles.forEach(file => {
    // Check if the file needs to be moved based on its path (or metadata)
    if (fileToBeMoved) {
        promises.push(file.move('....png'))
    }
});

await Promise.all(promises)
```