# Get list of images from Firebase Store

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I want to get **list of images** which I uploaded manually in web Firebase console. Is there any way I can get list of all files without using FirebaseRecyclerAdapter?

Comment: Where have you stored them and where you want to place them after download?

Comment: If you want to download images from Firebase storage I think the application must know all image names. While you stored them in `List<String>` for example you can use `Glide` external library for smooth and fast image download in `for` cycle.

Answer (score 1):

There is no existing method to extract the list of file name you have saved in Firestore. Instead you have to use some workaround to manually create a list. For example, maintaining a list of file and URL inside Firebase database.

One possible solution is to write a trigger using cloud functions, listening to the changes made to Firebase Storage.(as this time you are doing the upload directly through console, you have to write a trigger and host it in cloud function). Upon there is insertion/ removal/ modification in the attachment list, update the dummy file entries inside the firebase database. When you are trying to extract the list of file/ url information, retrieve them from database but not storage.

You may refer to below document for more information:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/gcp-storage-events?hl=zh-cn

[How to get a list of all files in Cloud Storage in a Firebase app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37335102/how-to-get-a-list-of-all-files-in-cloud-storage-in-a-firebase-app)

Answer (score 0):

There is no any functionality which can directly fetch your image from firebase storage so first of all, you have to create a database and in that add one field of Imageurl or something like that and then fetch that data or image from the URL using query. For the query build, I already mention code below use that.

```
 mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    Query query = mDatabase.child("DatabaseName").orderByChild("ImageUrl");
    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                // dataSnapshot is the "issue" node with all children with id 0
                for (DataSnapshot issue : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    // do something with the individual "issues"
                    try {
                        imgeListModel.add(issue.getValue(ImageListModel.class));
                        Log.e("Get Data", issue.getValue(ImageListModel.class).toString());
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
           databaseError.toException();
        }
    });
```