# How to find out the file-names in firebase order-URL programmatically?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I am using firebase and have an Order-URL with some .pdf-files in it. 
Here is an image, which shows it: 
[image]

I have this code:

```
   @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_wiki, container, false);

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    WebView webView = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    //FireBase Connection
    StorageReference mStorageRef;
    mStorageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
    mStorageRef.getDownloadUrl();


    String myPdfUrl = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/realtime-chat-46f4c.appspot.com/o/documents%2Fbf307aa5-79ae-4532-8128-ee394537b357.pdf?alt=media&token=2d0c5329-4717-4adc-9418-6614913e5bfa";
   /* String url = "http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" + myPdfUrl;
    webView.loadUrl(url);*/

    try {
        myPdfUrl = URLEncoder.encode(myPdfUrl,"UTF-8");
        webView.loadUrl("https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" + myPdfUrl);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return view;
}
```

What I want is: 
 - to get all the file-names of the Order-Url in firebase from the link, I show in the image above 
 - Get the url of the download path of each of the file-names in the order

When I just copy the download URL, I can easy add it in code and load the file. But I want it dynamically, means, always, when I add an file in this storage in firebase, it should be detected and added/removed, and so on.

I dont want to change my code all the time, just to add the new download-url of the files.

Does anybody have experience, or idea how to solve it?

Thanks a lot

Comment: There is no API in the Firebase SDK to get a listing of files from Storage. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37335102/how-to-get-a-list-of-all-files-in-cloud-storage-in-a-firebase-app

Answer (score 1):

Your use case sounds like a great opportunity to use [Firebase's Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/), particularly the [Cloud Storage trigger](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/gcp-storage-events)s part.

The basic idea is that you can write code which will be triggered whenever some event happens. In your case, the event is when files are uploaded to your "Order-Url" and you just need to write some code that will make a record of the download URLs for these files.

That approach is very much "ahead-of-time". As an alternative, you could use the [Google Storage SDK](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-java) or [APIs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/) to query the underlying storage bucket and folder that Firebase Storage uses for your files.

Comment: Thank you Tom, 
I will take a look to the "alternative", because I want to upload the files direct on browser, where the firebase-project is, and just updating code, depending on the bucket of this.