# Android Firebase Storage

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I am developing an Android app to share doc(generally pdf) between student and teachers(two different app one as a server and another as a client).Uploading a file to the firebase storage is done. The problem is that I want a list of uploaded file with download thumbnail/button in the student app. How to do it?
Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do it as there is no API till now. All you can do is Store the link generated for each file in the **Realtime database** and then use this list of URL.

Or use **cloud functions** to manipulate your uploads and then store generated URL in some file and retrieve this file for list of files.

For more please refer this post.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/37337436/4517450

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/