# Load folder of images from firebase storage

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-storage

How I can download folder of images from firebase **storage** and append in array?

My struct storage in firebase like this -

```
Storage.storage().reference().child("studioImages").child("cross +studio").child("СROSS в Москва-Сити").child("башня Око")
```

and then I have images with name:

- HallOko.jpg
- HallOko1.jpg
- HallOko2.jpg
- HallOko3.jpg

How i can load all four images in my empty array?

Comment: The Firebase SDK for Cloud Storage does not have an API to get a list of the files in a folder. You will have to keep that elsewhere, e.g. in the Firebase Database. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37335102/how-to-get-a-list-of-all-files-in-cloud-storage-in-a-firebase-app

Answer (score 0):

Save the image you get from the reference as? UIImage

You can use the observer property to get a snapshot of the images

Create a new UImage array and then append it.