# Retrieve all images from firebase storage

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I am trying to list all images uploaded in firebase storage, just like a media library. All samples I have seen so far, are getting a single image (with filename), not all images.

Does anybody has a sample of how to retrieve all images for storage?

Cheers

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37337436/7949696

Comment: You would typically store a reference to what you've uploaded to Storage in the Firebase Database - otherwise you wouldn't know the URL. If that's the case then you would have a list of that already. Is your use case different?