# Get all files from Firebase Storage

Tags: java, android

I was able to successfully store files in the firebase storage, but now I am having  a problem. I am storing multiple images in a directory / folder but I am only able to retrieve one? How do I iterate through all files in a folder? I know you can do this with FirebaseDatabase snapshots by using an enhanced for loop, but this is not possible for FirebaseStorage, no?

```
FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child(listing.authorUid).child(listing.adId).getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
       @Override
           public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
              //for(Uri child : uri.getChildren()) ???
           }
       });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get a list of all files in Cloud Storage in a Firebase app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37335102/how-to-get-a-list-of-all-files-in-cloud-storage-in-a-firebase-app)

Comment: Bad news: no way. That's one of the reasons why I gave up with Firebase.

Answer (score 0):

Use listall option with firebase storage reference. This will return the list of all files as items.

```
root.child('images/uid').listAll()
```

Will return the file as an item.