# Ii's possible to get how many elements have in firebase storage?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm doing an app to test firebase-storage and when i try to get a random element from the storage no idea how to get de amount of elements on the folder

Is a JS app to display random images from a firebase storage

```
var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * storage.length);
```

I expect a random number from 0 to max elements on the storage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to [list objects in a bucket](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/listing-objects) using a server SDK, but this won't scale very well when the number of objects in the bucket becomes large.  There is currently no list API for client SDKs.

Cloud Storage doesn't provide a simple way to count the number of objects in it.  You should be using a database to track this instead.

Comment: there actually **is** a method to list objects since [version 6.1](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js) in the client-side JavaScript SDK. I updated my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37335102/how-to-get-a-list-of-all-files-in-cloud-storage-in-a-firebase-app to point that out too.

Comment: To be fair, they accidentally released that API before it was supposed to be released, and without documenting it.  :-)

Comment: Yup, waiting for both the other platforms and documentation too. :)